# Is there anyway to make two dialogs of two different classes shown in the order we want?

Tags: java, android

I am working on two classes which generate information and show these information on two different dialogs. So, the code has format as below:

```
class A(){
    showDialogA();
}

class B(){
    showDialogB();
}
```

So, I want dialog A show up and done its work, then dialog B will show up. I tried like:

```
class B() {
    showDialogA();
    showDialogB();
}
```

However, the dialog B always show up before Dialog A. Or, after dialog A finishes, the dialog B does not show up as expectation.

How I can make the order: dialog A shows up -> dialog A finishes its work -> Dialog B shows up?

Thank you.

Comment: You can show dialog B in one of dialog A callbacks (cancel/dismiss listener, buttons listeners)

Comment: @SergeyGlotov thank you.